# Does this express/imply the mountains are behind the temple (not the pagoda)?

Tags: sentence-construction

> The pagoda is surrounded by Bailin temple, with mountains behind and a river in front.

I want to express the meaning that there are mountains behind the temple, not behind the pagoda. The pagoda is in the temple.

Does the sentence implies the mountains are behind the temple, or does it mean it is behind the pagoda? I'm not sure because 'the pagoda' is the subject of the sentence, maybe it expresses the meaning that the mountain is behind the pagoda (subject), not the temple.

Comment: The meaning is clear enough but it doesn't exactly "paint a picture". You may need to develop it depending on how you intend to use it.

Comment: Your sentence is not vague at all, but as the wording of your question makes clear, by now you know that this comes under the rubric of proofreading!

Comment: @P.E.Dant I think I have a problem with wording my questions... What I meant was does this imply the mountains are behind the temple, or does it mean it is behind the pagoda? I'm not sure because 'the pagoda' is the subject of the sentence, maybe it expresses the meaning that the mountain is behind the pagoda (subject), not the temple. I sincerely won't post it if I think it is proofreading.

Comment: I think the description is clear and evocative. Well done! (Think about this, though: to someone searching the ELL database five years from now, how will they find your question? Does it ask about something specific, or does it ask "Is this okay?" Is there any information for their benefit in _"You can vote close if you think it is off-topic, but please don't be aggressive."_ ...?)

Comment: @P.E.Dant I think it is very difficult to always ask questions that can be searched/find by others, some questions are not about rules, but have to be asked through an example. Well, it doesn't help if others reply 'use the dictionary'.

Comment: @P.E.Dant My point is, if many people think it is off-topic, the question will be closed, and I accept that. It doesn't help saying 'use the dictionary'.

Comment: What we hope is that new users will consult the dictionary first, and then, if they are still puzzled, ask a question here. It's not always easy to decide, though, whether a question can be answered with a dictionary. We try very hard to leave as many questions open as we can. Sometimes, I'm sure, we get it wrong, but our motivation is always to help new learners of English.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I do agree with you that it is not always easy to draw the line, and I admit that after receiving that kind of replies for a couple of times I guess I took it a bit personally. However, posts influence other people, maybe others won't post an answer after they saw someone identified the question as off-topic, I would very much like people take that into consideration. I don't think one can only post a question unless it will benefit all learners (e.g. other people can find the question by google the keyword.)